# Password field empty by default in razor syntax

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-pages

when the page loads my password fields show some dots by default.First I have to delete the dots and then enter my password, I want the password field empty by default.

```html
<label>Password</label>
    @Html.Password("password", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:200px" } })
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
@Html.Password("password", new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = "", @class = "form-control", @style = "width:200px" } })

if error:

@Html.Password("password", new { @Value = "", htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:200px" } })
```